# how to obtain the post data in binary of PHP

Tags: php, post, binary

I want to post some binary data to PHP.
I know that I can use php://input or $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA to read it.
But it only can post one binary data.
I want to post two key-value data which respective value is in binary.
How can we do this in PHP?

Comment: If you use either of those, you only have one *post-body* and it's your responsibility to handle it the way you need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can encode your binary data in Base64 using [**`base64_encode()`**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-encode.php) and [**`base64_decode()`**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-decode.php).

> Base64 encoding schemes are commonly used when there is a need to
>   encode binary data that needs to be stored and transferred over media
>   that are designed to deal with textual data.

For example, you can post:

```
key1=eW91cmJpbmFyeWRhdGE=&key2=YmluYXJ5YWdhaW4=
```

And in your PHP:

```
$myBinaryData1 = base64_decode($_POST['key1']);
$myBinaryData2 = base64_decode($_POST['key2']);
```

Comment: That makes the data bigger though. You should be able to handle binary data in a `$_POST['key']` value...